# Wordpress Core Update Fail (4.1 to 4.1.1)

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have Wordpress 4.1, trying to update to 4.1.1.

I've updated several times in the past via the Dashboard > Updates module. This time around, when I attempt to update, I'm met with a blank page after entering my FTP password.

The "blank" page isn't entirely blank. The top and left menus of the dashboard show, but the content area is blank. The URL of the page is @HOME/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-upgrade&_wpnonce=7b6cf80aad

I've tried using the default theme, as well as disabling all plugins. Nothing changes.

On one occasion, I caught these errors in the Google Chrome console:

```
Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

Failed to create temp file 2 : It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.
```

This is ONLY happening with the Core Update. I can still install/delete plugins no problem. What other factors could affect the core update in this fashion?

Comment: I seemed to be having the same issue just a bit ago. Maybe it was unrelated, but removing the `wp-content/upgrade` folder seemed to solve the issue for me.

Comment: That didn't work me, unfortunately.

Comment: [It looks like we aren't the only ones](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-to-411-not-working).

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the link. Please post here if you find anything relevant.

Comment: Interestingly enough, another website I manage auto-updated successfully. It might just be an issue with manually updating.

Comment: Did you made a backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to put your ftp credentials into the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'FTP_USER', 'ftpusername' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'ftppassword' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.hostname.net:21' );
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-upgrade-vom-41-to-411?replies=10#post-6589194

Comment: Yep, had just tried this prior to you posting, and it worked for me. Hoping future updates will address this issue - I actually prefer entering credentials before any install.

Answer (score 2):

just add below code into your theme `function.php`.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

after add this code Wordpress not ask FTP details. You can get [more detail from here](https://thecodingstuff.com/install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access/).

and give 777 permission to `uploads` directory.

then check i hope it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Switch you PHP handler to FastCGI or PHP-FPM and the issue is gone.

Comment: Seems like an extremely harsh decision based on one script breaking from one version to the next minor one (4.1 -> 4.1.1). I would not go with this route but try to find a patch for wordpress itself first.

Comment: Agreeing with @Purefan here.

Comment: You should consider switching to FastCGI or better PHP-FPM in general and not only for this purpose. MOD-PHP has done its job for a long time but now it is time to retire.